# C, K&R Exercise 1-6, stuck, confused

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

I am a noob teaching myself to program in C using *The C Programming Language, Second Edition* (by *K&R*).  In Chapter 1 Section **1.5.1 File Copying**, the authors touch very briefly on operational precedence when making comparison between values, underscoring the importance of using parenthesis, in this case, to ensure that assignment is made to the variable 'c' before the comparison is evaluated. They make the assertion that:

```
    c = getchar() != EOF
```

is equivalent to

```
    c = (getchar() != EOF)
```

Which "has the undesired effect of setting `c` to 0 or 1, depending on whether or not the call of getchar encountered end of file"

The authors then pose **Excercise 1-6** - Verify that the expression `getchar () != EOF` is 0 or 1

Based on the author's previous assertion, this seemed almost trivial so I created this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;

    while (c = (getchar() != EOF))
        putchar(c);
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run the program, it simply outputs whatever characters I type in the command window rather than the expected string of 1 or 0 if EOF is encountered.

While I am a noob, I think I get the logic that the authors are trying to teach and yet I can not demonstrate this simple task. In this case, should not the variable `c` take on the value that the comparison expression evaluated to rather than whatever character `getchar()` happens to fetch, particularly because of the location of the parenthesis? If `c` is indeed taking on the value of the comparison, `putchar()` should only output 0 or 1 and yet, as formulated, it outputs what I type in the command window.   What am I doing wrong? What do I not understand? Could it be my compiler? I am coding in in Visual Studio 2017 Community edition on Windows 10 on x64 architecture. I have Tiny C Compiler but have not tried executing from command prompt with TCC yet.

Comment: The integer values `0` or `1` are not really printable characters in any encoding. Use e.g. `printf("%d\n", i)` instead.

Comment: Maybe OP is seeing whatever input OP gives..Yes those are not something menaingful

Comment: Maybe `((c = getchar()) != EOF)`??

Comment: Guys. I'm amazed at your rapid commenting speed.

Comment: And NO it is not your compiler. Make sure you are using the VS Developer Console and using `cl` (`cl.exe`) from the command line with the minimum options `cl /nologo /Wall /Ox /Feyourexe /Tc yoursource.c` (you can add `/Fo`, e.g. `/Foobjfile` to name the object file as well) It helps to have `obj` and `bin` subdirectories to keep your soucefile dir clean and use `/Foobj/thename /Febin/thename /Tc thename.c` to put the object files in the `obj` subdir and the executables in the `bin` subdir. Good luck. (use `/wd####` to suppresse individual warnings)

Comment: I poked this code into a mingw-gcc environment and changed to `putchar(c?'1':'0');` and got no output.  I put an `fflush(stdout);` after the `putchar()` and then I see output, but only after hitting enter.  I think the POSIX implementations of this function may vary from the expectations of the K&R authors.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b Because **input and output are both line-buffered**.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b  So standard C library function no longer operate they way that K&R authors would have understood them in their time? Are standard libraries truly standard across platform or are they platform dependent?

Comment: @H3G3moKnight You may not be understanding ***line-buffered*** correctly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
This was helpful, thanks.

Comment: @iBug: I think I don't understand it well enough either.  Do you happen to have a reference?

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b There's already [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36573578/5958455) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b And [the GNU manual for libc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Buffering-Concepts.html).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you misread the question

Comment: @M.M - chock another up to my misread list -- certainly isn't my first, and probably won't be my last...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala How did you add 3 dupe links?

Comment: @iBug Mjölnir wielders can add up to 5 dupe links with a simple edit functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run the program, the characters that you see **doesn't come from your program**. It's the console (or terminal)'s [**echo**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_(computing)) funcion that shows whatever character you have typed (and you can even erase them before you hit Enter). Your program only outpus **characters with ASCII code 0 or 1**, both of which are invisible.

If you change `putchar(c)` to `printf("%d", c)` you'll be able to see a sequence of `1`s. No zero will appear because when `c` becomes zero, the loop stops and it won't be printed.

Characters `'0'` and `'1'` have the ASCII code of 48 and 49, respectively, despite the fact that your terminal may use another encoding. If you want to output a literal number 0, use the character notation. You can also try `putchar(48)` but don't use this too much (You'll later find out that [it's highly discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882/5958455) to use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in your program).

```
putchar('0');
        ^ ^
```

The assertion that

```
c = getchar() != EOF;
```

is equivalent to

```
c = (getchar() != EOF);
```

is because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). The operator `!=` (inequality) has a higher precedence over `=` (value assignment), so it gets evaluated prior to assignment.

Finally, it's *extremely* rare for someone to have written that. The correct intention is to write this:

```
while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF )
```

Comment: Great explanation, and I learned something about the echo function that I did not know previously, thank you!

Comment: @H3G3moKnight I added a link for ***echo***.

Comment: I disagree with `Despite not being always, character...`. ASCII is always ASCII, even if the OS/Terminal uses a different code page the first 7 bits of ASCII give the same values. Encodings however can indeed differ.

Comment: @MatanShahar Re-worded.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is `c = (getchar() != EOF)` it will get one input character and then it compares. Result will be `1` in case it is not EOF. Then it is assigned. The value of assignment statement is the value that is being assigned. It enters the loop. Prints the character **having ascii value `1`**. But that character is non-printable so you don't see anything.

Once it gets `EOF` it will break from the loop. So you never get to see anything other than the character which has ascii value of `1`.(Even you don't see that also as it is non-printable). These are known as `ascii-control` characters. (Not belong to the printable class).

Also you said as `c=0` or `c=1` it should print `0` or `1`. Then try this simple code

```
int c= 68;
putchar(c);
```

Check the output and you will get the idea what happens when we try to print. It's the character whose ascii code is `68`, that is printed, not the value `68`.

The right way to do it would be `((c = getchar()) != EOF)`.

<sub>Originally I mentioned that on some machines it prints some funny characters. The representation of the non-printable characters depend on the used charset. It might be some non-standard encoding (non-unicode) which assigns to the ascii code `1` some representation.(breaking the idea of nonprintables)</sub>

Comment: Yes, I just looked up the ASCII character table and can see that "values 0 through 31, and 127, represent non-printable control characters."  This would explain a lot.

Comment: At least you see ASCII 10 (`\n`), right?

Comment: @iBug.: Yep....