# using printf and write together

Tags: c, printf, unistd.h

I would like to understand why when I execute this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    write(1, "6", 1);
    printf(" | ");
    write(1, "6", 1);
}
```

I get this output

```
66 | %
```

Instead of

```
6 | 6%
```

even with sleep before and after the printf it doesn't fix it.
Thanks

Comment: See [Accepted Answer - What do fully buffered, line buffered and unbuffered mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36573578/3422102) What happens if you add `fflush (stdout);` after each command??? Or `fflush (stdout);` after the first two commands and change the last to `write(1, "6\n", 2);`

Comment: It works with the fflush(stdout); thanks you, so if I understand the link you gave me,  the write function write instantly to stdout and printf wait a newline or to fill his buffer before printing it to stdout ?!?

Comment: Yes. `printf()` is *line-buffered* so it doesn't print anything until a `'\n'` is encountered (or the underlying buffer is filled -- it's large). So you use `fflush()` to force all the buffered characters to be written. `fflush()` is only needed after `printf()` because `write` will write the `'6'` to stdout. `printf()` will buffer `" | "`, the final `write()` will write another `'6'` before program exit (which flushes all streams). So placing `fflush()` after `printf()` keeps the output in the order written.

Comment: Detail, `stdout` is _usually_ line-buffered.

Comment: Thanks u a lot my friend that make more sense ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try fflush(stdout);
The file I/O is buffered to improve performance. Fflush writes the buffers out. Mixing the 2 may still give you surprises, so I would not recommend doing it.